# How to get array from json with resttemplate

Tags: android, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

My json looks like

```
{

  "lent_items": [
    "item1",
    "item2"
  ],

  "lent_pessoas": [
    "person1",
    "person2"
  ],

  "id": "login"

}
```

Im doing

```
Pessoa pessoa = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Pessoa.class);
```

Pessoa class has 3 attributes

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Pessoa {

private String id;
private ArrayList<String> lent_items;
private ArrayList<String> lent_pessoas;
```

I can get the id from the json, but not the arrays

Comment: your response is wrong i think..you have to put arrays values in json object.

Comment: @kaushik please check carefully, in that question, its jsonarray in jsonobject. and here its normal array. not json array..

Comment: @Slade no man those are `JSON Array` having **dynamic key** open [json viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) in browser and paste this response it is a valid one

Comment: Its very simple ma just juse JSONObject and json Array

Comment: Bros, its actually a problem with Jackson. Its not mapping the attributes as it should. Idk why but I just recreated the variables with different names and it worked.